# Axios redirects to wrong Action

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, axios, asp.net-apicontroller

I have a problem with my code. When I run the "DeleteEvent" function is redirecting me to event details. I'm not very familiar with axios or APIs, any help is appreciated.

The Controller name is EventController and action Delete.

```
  C#:
    [HttpDelete]
    [Authorize]
    public IActionResult Delete(int eventId)
    {
        _eventService.DeleteEvent(eventId);
        return Ok();
    }



 View:
    <td>
        <a onclick="DeleteEvent(@theEvent.Id)"><i class="fas fa-trash-alt iicon cursor-pointer"></i></a>
      </td>



<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/axios/dist/axios.min.js"></script>
<script>
        function DeleteEvent(theEventId) {
    var url = "https://localhost:44380/Event/Delete";
    var data = {
        eventId = theEventId,
    }
    axios.delete(url, data)
        .then(function (response) {
        })
        .catch(function (error) {
        })
}
</script>
```

[image: ErrorStatus]

```
DELETE /Event/Delete?eventId=1051 undefined
Host: localhost:44380
Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*
Referer: https://localhost:44380/User/Dashboard
Origin: https://localhost:44380
Connection: keep-alive


Response { type: "basic", url: "https://localhost:44380/Event/Delete?eventId=1051", redirected: false, status: 404, ok: false, statusText: "Not Found", headers: Headers, body: ReadableStream, bodyUsed: false }
​
```

Answer (score 0):

To invoke your current `Delete` endpoint, the `eventId` parameter is expected in the URL's query string, like `Event/Delete?eventId=42`. So, you'd call delete on the client after constructing such a URL:

```
var baseUrl = "https://localhost:44380/Event/Delete";
var requestUrl = baseUrl + "?eventId=" + theEventId;

axios.delete(requestUrl).then(...)
```

With axios, providing a `data` parameter value is intended as a request body, not a query string.

You also need to decorate the controller method with the expected HTTP verb (delete):

```
[HttpDelete]
[Authorize]
public IActionResult Delete(int eventId)
{
    _eventService.DeleteEvent(eventId);
    return Ok();
}
```

Comment: Still, it doesn't work. It's taking the event Id correctly, but I'm not sure why after it opens the event instead of deleting it. NS_BINDING_ABORTED

Comment: Does the `Delete` method get called when you debug with a breakpoint there?

Comment: Status is blocked  - NS_BINDING_ABORTED

Comment: Noah Stahl - No, is not getting to Delete method

Comment: I add the verb Delete too [HttpDelete] but still I'm getting blocked status :|

Comment: You may need to call `preventDefault()` on the event in the handler or return false. See searches on that error.

Comment: Why in the request headers there is "DELETE /Event/Delete?eventId=1051 undefined"